# Trouble converting Degrees minutes seconds to decimal degree with Python

Tags: python-2.7, math

I have a .dat file that contains thousands of records each of which includes separate Degree Minute Seconds fields.  I'm trying to convert this to Decimal Degrees, which is the standard for most mapping/GIS software.

The math for the conversion is very simple, but I'm not getting the expected output.  I'm assuming this is because the data exist as `string`s that I cast to `int` and `float` types for the calculation.

Here is the calculation looks like this:
`latitude = (degs+(mins/60)+(secs/3600))`

**Script:**

```
import csv

georgia = r'C:\Users\rhewitt\Desktop\CellTowers\DOF\13-GA.Dat'
output = r'C:\Users\rhewitt\Desktop\CellTowers\CSV\georgia.csv'
header = r'C:\Users\rhewitt\Desktop\CellTowers\header.csv'

dat = open(georgia, 'r')
f = open(output, 'wb')
wr = csv.writer(f, quoting=csv.QUOTE_ALL)

# Create header
header = ["ObstacleNo", "ver_status", "Country", "State", "City", "latdeg", "latmin", "latsec", "N_S", "latitude", "londeg", "lonmin", "lonsec", "E_W", "longitude", "Type", "QTY", "AGL_HT", "AMSL_HT", "Lighting", "horz_acc", "vert_acc", "marking", "FAA_no", "Action", "Julian_dt"]
wr.writerow(header)

i=-1
for line in dat:
    i+=1

    # The top five rows of the .dat file contains header information (skip them)
    if i < 5:
        continue

    # .dat files have fixed-width columns, so I can pull out information like this:
    else:
        ORS     = line[:9]
        v       = line[9:11]
        country = line[11:14]
        state   = line[14:17]
        city    = line[17:35]
        latDeg  = line[35:37]
        latMin  = line[37:40]
        latSec  = line[40:46]
        latHem  = line[46:47]
        lonDeg  = line[47:51]
        lonMin  = line[51:54]
        lonSec  = line[54:60]
        lonHem  = line[60:61]
        obType  = line[61:75]
        uknown  = line[75:76]
        agl     = line[76:82]
        amsl    = line[82:88]
        lt      = line[88:90]
        ah      = line[90:92]
        ccv     = line[92:94]
        MIN     = line[94:96]
        study   = line[96:111]
        action  = line[111:113]
        jDate   = line[113:]

        # Convert Degrees Minutes Seconds to Decimal Degrees for easier mapping
        if latHem == "N":
            latitude = (int(latDeg)+(int(latMin)/60)+(float(latSec)/3600))
        else:
            latitude = -1*(int(latDeg)+(int(latMin)/60)+(float(latSec)/3600))

        if lonHem == "E":
            longitude = (int(lonDeg)+(int(lonMin)/60)+(float(lonSec)/3600))
        else:
            longitude = -1*(int(lonDeg)+(int(lonMin)/60)+(float(lonSec)/3600))

        csvLine = [ORS, v, country, state, city, latDeg, latMin, latSec, latHem, latitude, lonDeg, lonMin, lonSec, lonHem, longitude, obType, uknown, agl, amsl, lt, ah, ccv, MIN, study, action, jDate.rstrip("\n")]
        wr.writerow(csvLine)

f.close()
dat.close()
```

Here is an example output from my script:
`(34 + (59/60)+(10.00/3600)) = 34.0027777778`, but the correct value is actually `34.9861111111`

Comment: It's an integer division thing, `59/60 == 0`

Comment: @stranac So does everything have to be a float?

Comment: If either of the two is a float, the result will be a float. Or you can `from __future__ import division` to use real division.

Comment: Thanks; casting each value to a `float` (rather than int, int, float) fixed the issue.